# Lattice based encryption, current status?

Tags: post-quantum

I see that a couple of years ago, post-quantum was a "5+ year horizon" project.  Is that still the case?

[NTRUEncrypt in SSL and GPG encryption](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/122145/ntruencrypt-in-ssl-and-gpg-encryption/122150#122150?newreg=4b7f24c193dd46f59833e2df3db7a035)

As the final comment on that thread said, a two-layer approach, with something currently trusted like RSA, plus a (less-than-completely-proven) quantum safe layer, should be a safe transition: at least as secure as RSA, and as quantum safe as we can guess anything to be at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NIST post-quantum crypto competition is [currently underway](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Post-Quantum-Cryptography). When it is completed, NIST will be ready to issue a new standard for post-quantum cryptography. Until this happens, many people are reluctant to roll out their own favorite PQ scheme. There are three specific projects which are working on post-quantum cryptography (specifically PQ key exchange) that I can think of:

- WolfSSL is a TLS library which [supports NTRUEncrypt](https://www.wolfssl.com/quantum-safe-wolfssl-2/) in its cipher suites.
- The Tor Project has an open ticket for [introducing a hybrid handshake](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/24985) into the protocol.
- Google has been [experimenting with their CECPQ1 algorithm](https://security.googleblog.com/2016/07/experimenting-with-post-quantum.html) recently.

Many post-quantum designs are actually hybrid designs. Both Tor Project's and Google's designs combine x25519 with NewHope so that, if a classical algorithm is found that can break the relatively new lattice-based crypto, the handshake is still at least as secure as x25519.